# Add between two VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to add 2 `VLOOKUP` together but when it does not find the target, it gives me an error.

```
=Vlookup(A1, 'TestA'!A1:B5, 5, 0) + Vlookup(A1, 'TestB'!A1:B5, 5, 0) + 1
```

The issue is that when either (or both) Vlookup are not found, it gives an error `#N/A` instead of just displaying the answer "1".

I am trying to look for an answer but most of the answers are regarding issues between adding `VLOOKUP` from 2 different sheets and not regarding my specific issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears you want the result to be 1 if either of the `VLOOKUP` return an error. Can you confirm?

Comment: You can't use `5` as the third parameter of `VLOOKUP` if your lookup table is 2 columns wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `IfNA` function:

```
=IfNA(Vlookup(A1, 'TestA'!A1:B5, 5, 0),0) + IfNA(Vlookup(A1, 'TestB'!A1:B5, 5, 0),0) + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `IFERROR`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,'TestA'!A1:B5,2,0) + VLOOKUP(A1, 'TestB'!A1:B5, 2, 0), 0) + 1
```

It appears from your question that you want the result to be 1 if  *either* of the `VLOOKUP` returns an error. If that's not the case, then wrap each `VLOOKUP` in `IFERROR`:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,'TestA'!A1:B5,2,0),0) + IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1, 'TestB'!A1:B5,2,0),0) + 1
```

Comment: Using `IFNA()` won't parse errors that returns `#VALUE!` OP needs `IFERROR()` here. I'm sure OP will realize that sooner or later.